# Как определить, есть у элемента скролл или нет?

Tags: javascript

Есть всплывающее окно у него на широком мониторе нет скролла, а на узком есть скролл.

Когда всплывает окно, я убираю скролл у `body`, и если у всплывающего окна есть скролл, то все выглядит нормально, но если нет, происходит содрогание за счет того, что все содержимое страницы смещается на ширину скрола:

Как узнать, есть ли у элемента скролл или нет?

Конечно, можно сравнивать высоту окна браузера с высотой содержимого всплывающего окна, но для этого придется учитывать все внутренние отступы всплывающего окна и все наружные отступы дочерних элементов. Это потребует больших усилий и скорее всего не надежный способ.

А есть какой-нибудь встроенный метод?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нашел способ:

```
elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight
```

`scrollHeight` - это высота элемента полностью.

`clientHeight` - это видимая "клиентская" высота элемента.

Если скролла нет, то эти две величины равны, в противном случае `scrollHeight` будет больше `clientHeight`, и выражение будет равно `true`, что удобно использовать в условиях.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Обычно используют подобие такой функции, или просто сравнение (как в возвращаемом объекте): 
function getScrollbarsVisibility(el) {
  return {
    h: el.scrollWidth  > el.clientWidth, 
    v: el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight
  }; 
}

var content = document.getElementById('content'); 
document.getElementById('test').onclick = () => {
  let sv = getScrollbarsVisibility(content.parentElement); 
  console.clear(); 
  console.log(`Горизонтальный: ${sv.h ? '' : 'не'}видим. Вертикальный: ${sv.v ? '' : 'не'}видим.`); 
  setTimeout(console.clear, 3000); 
}; 

document.getElementById('add-h').onclick = () => { content.style.width  = '150vw'; }; 
document.getElementById('add-v').onclick = () => { content.style.height = '150vh'; };
```

```css
body > div { float: left; }

#block {
  width: 200px; height: 110px;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  overflow: auto; 
}

#content {
  height: 100%; 
  background: radial-gradient(at center, black 5%, black, green, #af7, green 40%, black 60%, black); 
}

button {
  display: block; 
  width: 300px; 
  margin: 10px 0;
  font: 18px sans-serif; 
}

hr { width: 50%; }
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="test">Проверить скроллбары</button>
  <hr>
  <button id="add-v">Включить вертикальный</button>
  <button id="add-h">Включить горизонтальный</button>
</div>
<div id="block"><div id="content">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

А стандартного метода, вроде нет.